# Docusign Node.JS JWT example - PEM_read_bio:bad end line

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I'm trying to run the DocuSign https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-node-jwt example and am getting a PEM error - PEM_read_bio:bad end line

I originally had a Start line error which was corrected as I had missed the -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- and END Key comments so this points to another issue with the private key. I've tried various different quote marks and changing how the key is formatted but still get the error

Googling the error gives me answer re the format or the number of dashes but all this seems correct

The readme says you can use an Environment Variable but these don't seem to accept such a long string - if I cur and paste I only get the start of the first line

I'm using the dsconfig.js from the example

```
  /** The private key */
    /** Enter the key as a multiline string value. No leading spaces! */
  , privateKey: env.DS_PRIVATE_KEY ||   `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  MIIEogIBAAKCAQEAgXxpEI/it1KvSFTgduXIAbBBqnwTZXasyt4AaBHkuw+VFyhk
………..
  10kBAoGASgk77R0K87kUOvqLTDYQydV6pMyenLuGt+KsqsaiHwxO8/x53JEJn710
  uYJku2KMSAKndzlPnYfDw9yFN9BxENvzKzL4oRa8Lbfq+ziHFlfRiNvO1ebNURV5
  YNdbhBO4UfTx8808l84bNbL5e+2/w4O9FmoeUD1pO0H1RQCtDiI=
  -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`
```

(Deleted the middle part of the key)

So when I run start I get this error

c:\Users..\eg-01-node-jwt-master>npm start

> docusign_eg01_oauth_jwt_authentication@1.0.0 start c:\Users..\eg-01-node-jwt-master
>   node index.js

Send an envelope with three documents. This operation takes about 15 seconds...

```
checkToken: Starting up--need an accessToken
(node:14568) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: error:0906D066:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:bad end line
at Sign.sign (internal/crypto/sig.js:80:26)
at Object.sign (c:\Users\..\eg-01-node-jwt-master\node_modules\jwa\index.js:76:45)
at Object.jwsSign [as sign] (c:\Users\..\eg-01-node-jwt-master\node_modules\jws\lib\sign-stream.js:32:24)
at Object.module.exports [as sign] (c:\Users\..\eg-01-node-jwt-master\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\sign.js:189:16)
at generateAndSignJWTAssertion (c:\Users\..\eg-01-node-jwt-master\node_modules\docusign-esign\src\ApiClient.js:62:16)
at exports.requestJWTUserToken (c:\Users\..\eg-01-node-jwt-master\node_modules\docusign-esign\src\ApiClient.js:881:19)
at Object._getToken [as getToken] (c:\Users\..\eg-01-node-jwt-master\lib\dsJwtAuth.js:94:31)
at Object._checkToken [as checkToken] (c:\Users..\eg-01-node-jwt-master\lib\dsJwtAuth.js:65:35)
at Object._sendEnvelope [as sendEnvelope] (c:\Users..\eg-01-node-jwt-master\lib\sendEnvelope.js:62:19)
at main (c:\Users\..\eg-01-node-jwt-master\index.js:40:36)
```

(node:14568) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:14568) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: You need to re-format your key to be one line, I've posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm, sorry you're having this trouble.

Ergin's answer may also work. Personally, I haven't needed to remove the new lines on a Mac. If you're using Windows, maybe that's different.

Items to check:

- node --version should return v8.11 or later
- Ensure that you're using your private key from the Admin tool, not the public key.
- Ensure that you're using backticks -- ` to surround the RSA private key.
- Ensure that environment variable DS_PRIVATE_KEY is not set. Or maybe easier, remove it from the line.
- Ensure that your client_id (Integration key) is correct.

eg

```
, privateKey: `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAkbz3bi31zrH2ry4p8S4ncPoMdkUyu+MG46m9BalOKzWNNAvW
1LVs5ftlXxzA6V0m6nx895w8S761/qZ8xtAAl99DezRn/3CueeBUyw+tvlmEBu1C
IJK69GVoSInIKf6qyeL1WxxFV5R17QtIiQeT2yCa/fitCaxwxkNlYpP4wd5tcG0W
PEHgznlGh/vUboCuA4tQOcKytxFfKG4F+jM/g4GH9z46KZOow3Hb6g==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`
```

Lines were left out.

To debug, put a breakpoint at line 93 of https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-node-jwt/blob/master/lib/dsJwtAuth.js

And then evaluate expression `dsConfig.privateKey`

Comment: Cheers - This pointed me in the right direction . After trying the above found it was to do with format o f the Key

Comment: Great! Glad it's working for you. Thank you for the check.

Answer (score 2):

This is a key formatting issue, to resolve:

1. Open your key in using your favorite text editor (I like [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/)).
2. Select the entire key value.
3. Do a regex replace of any `\n` sequence in your key with `\\n`
4. Use the newly modified key in your request and it should work.

Note: If using Sublime make sure you have the Regular Expression option enabled when doing the find/replace otherwise it won't work.

Comment: thanks Ergin!  Your comment to the original question helped me most to solve this.  Pasting the key from the docusign API into VSCode within backticks resulted in the same issue.  I fixed it by removing leading spaces inserted due to indent and replacing the hidden new lines with '\n' as you suggest.  My key looks like this now:

`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEowIBAA.......E3\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n`